# Send an image from the iPhone using ASIHTTP and UIImagePicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http

Using examples such as the one below from [this website](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) I am trying to send a photo selected with UIImagePickerController.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"names"];
[request addPostValue:@"George" forKey:@"names"];
[request addFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photos"];
[request addData:imageData withFileName:@"george.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photos"];

imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
NSLog(@"  %@ ",  imageURL);
stringURL = [imageURL absoluteString];
```

I don't get how to connect these two chunks of code. I would like to use this url to locate the image on my iPhone and then send it with the ASIHTTP code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to save the image and keep track of the filename or filepath. Here I used a time interval to create unique image names. photoImage is the UIImage that you want to store.

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSString *photoName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf-Photo.jpeg",timeInterval];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
// the path to write file
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:photoName];
NSData * photoImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photoImage, 1.0);
[photoImageData writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
```

Then you go and grab the file path using the filename that you stored or if you already stored the file path then skip to the next bit.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:photoName];
```

Then we make the HTTP request to send the data at said file path.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.requestMethod = @"POST";
[request setFile:filePath forKey:@"file1"];
[request startSynchronous];
```